# Getting 400 response code instead of 200 code when testing multipart files upload

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockmvc

I am testing an endpoint to upload an array of multipart files along with a `String` parameter. I am getting the 400 response instead of the `200 (OK)`. Any thoughts on why I am getting `400 response`, which indicates something wrong with my request object. But when I checked the request, the content type is correct.

uploadMyFiles.java endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/uploadMyFiles", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public Map<String, String> uploadMyFiles(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles, String userName) {
//..
return statusMap
}
```

My test case

```
@Test
 public void testUploadMyFiles() throws Exception {
        byte[] byteContent = new byte[100];
        String userName ="testUser"
        
        MockMultipartFile filePart1 = new MockMultipartFile("files", "file1.pdf", "multipart/form-data", content);
        MultipartFile[] multipartFiles={filePart1}
        
        Object resultMap;
        when(myService.uploadMyFiles(multipartFiles,userName)).thenReturn(Map.of("file1.pdf", "Success"));

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/uploadMyFiles")
                            .content(userName)
                            .content("{userName:testUser}") //tried with this too
                            .param("userName", "testUser")) //tried with this too 
                            .andExpect(status().isOk())
                            .andReturn();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, ((ResponseEntity)result.getAsyncResult()).getStatusCode());
    }
```

Debug:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /uploadMyFiles
       Parameters = {userName=[testUser]}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"multipart/form-data", Content-Length:"23"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}
```

response

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP 400 (in spring-web) indicates, that a RequestMapping only "partially maps" ...

To test this Controller/RequestMapping:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadMyFiles", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    Map<String, String> uploadMyFiles(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles, String userName) {
        if (multipartFiles == null) {
            LOG.warn("multipartFiles is null!");
        } else {
            LOG.info("{} file{} uploaded.", multipartFiles.length, multipartFiles.length > 1 ? "s" : "");
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                for (MultipartFile mf : multipartFiles) {
                    LOG.debug("name: {}, size: {}, contentType: {}", mf.getOriginalFilename(), mf.getSize(), mf.getContentType());
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
        return Map.of("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

This would be the outline of a MockMvc test(, which hits this controller):

```
package com.example; // package of spring-boot-app

    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest
class Q66280300ApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testUploadMyFiles() throws Exception {
        byte[] byteContent1 = "text1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        byte[] byteContent2 = "text2".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        String userName = "testUser";

        // IMPORTANT: name = "multipartFiles" (name of the request parameter)
        MockMultipartFile filePart1 = new MockMultipartFile("multipartFiles", "file1.txt", "text/plain", byteContent1);
        MockMultipartFile filePart2 = new MockMultipartFile("multipartFiles", "file2.txt", "text/plain", byteContent2);

        this.mockMvc.perform(
          multipart("/uploadMyFiles")
          .file(filePart1)
          .file(filePart2)
          .param("userName", userName)
        )
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}")));

    }
}
```

And to find your files (inside the controller, logging, null...) it *is crucial*, that the name of `MockMultipartFile` *matches* the name of the request parameter. (in our case the "default" name of method parameter: `"multipartFiles"` )

Code bases on [Spring-boot-starter:2.4.3](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.3.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo).

Comment: Thank you very much for adding comment // IMPORTANT: name = "multipartFiles" (name of the request parameter). This helped to solve my problem